# Redis cache annotations vs redistemplate

Tags: spring-boot, caching, spring-data-redis

I am using Redis as cache with a spring boot project and i got to know there are two ways of using redis as cache for spring boot . First one is to use annotations like @cacheable , @cacheevict etc. and other to use redistemplate and to use methods like redistemplate.opsForHash().get(). I am confused about these two. What is the difference between the two and when to use what?